# Unable to get element width on page refresh

Tags: javascript, css, width, element

I have the following code:

```
  //get the largest block: if no block, apply to first block
  var previous = $('.block-grid .block-group .block.block-lg');

  var blocks = $('.block-grid .block-group .block');

  blocks.last().css({'left': (previous.width() + previous.position().left), 'top':    previous.position().top});
```

When I refresh the page, this part: `previous.width()`, returns 0. Normally it is supposed to return 400, which is the size of the largest block. However, when I navigate to the page's URL, it return 400. Why would a page refresh make the width value 0? I am very confused and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A page refresh runs all of your javascript again - and I am assuming 'previous' is set in your code, so to maintain the previous state either, hardcode it if viable, set a cookie to keep 'previous' on next page load and then read that, push the 'previous' value into the session in whatever backend language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually managed to get this working. It was a very simple solution. I simply wrapped my solution in a `$(window).load()`, so it looks something like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){

  //get the largest block: if no block, apply to first block
  var previous = $('.block-grid .block-group .block.block-lg');

  var blocks = $('.block-grid .block-group .block');

  blocks.last().css({'left': (previous.width() + previous.position().left), 'top':    previous.position().top});

});
```